# SQL Server : select from inserted

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I am working on a insert trigger and I wondering if I use the line:

```
SET @ProductID = (SELECT ProductID FROM inserted)
```

will this give me the `ProductID` that was inserted into the table or will it have to be read using select?

Comment: `@ProductID` is a variable, not a column of any table (including the `inserted` metatable).

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? SQL is just a query language not a specific DBMS product. And triggers are **highly* DBMS dependent

Answer (score 4):

`inserted` can contain multiple records and your trigger logic should be able to handle that. Preferably you should to use a regular `SELECT` statement to get all the records from `inserted` as cursoring over the records can result in a significant performance overhead.

```
SELECT ProductID FROM INSERTED
```

Comment: I believe there is also a "table" for DELETED